# mapbox library of public styles to use

Tags: styles, mapbox

sorry, as I am new... where can I find all mapbox library of public styles that I can upload and use in studio ?  in mabox site there is only 4 styles, but users created lot public ones , where those can be downloaded?

Comment: Did you find something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#mapbox-styles
- https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/

filler text to meet stack overflow 30 char minimum, sigh.

Comment: thanks a lot.  I was in this URL's,  it shows onlt few mapbox styles, i look for the gallery fo all users that publish thier styles publically,   and it says its in twitter  "#BuiltWithMapbox " ,  but there its not published in a manner it can be reused.

Comment: The gallery shows styles in use, but you cannot download them...